# Can't add documents and collections to Cloud Firestore to trigger Translate Text extension

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-extensions

[image]

I tried to use [Firebase Translate Text Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-translate-text) to translate a text in my chat app project with Javascript. To do that, I have to add the target text **into “document”** at the Cloud Firestore ([Add data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)), but had the error:

*"Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions."*

```
const docRef = await db.collection('translations').add({
    input: document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML,
    created: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()
});
console.log(docRef);
```

✔︎ Firebase rules are default.
✔︎ Firebase Deploy completed successfully
✔︎ Firebase Realtime Database works correctly
×  Can't add document to Firestore Database data


I just followed [this GitHub sample code](https://github.com/tabyasu/google-translate-on-firebase/blob/master/sample.html).
Please someone help me out.
Thank you very much in your advance.

Firestore Rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false; //changed to "true" and it works
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the user running this code does not have permission to write to the database. I recommend checking out some of the existing [questions about this error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+Uncaught+(in+promise)+FirebaseError%3A+Missing+or+insufficient+permissions) to learn how to fix that.

Comment: Can you post the rules that you say are 'default' - are they closed or open?

Comment: @DIGIByte I changed "write: if true;" and it works. Thank you for your suggestion!